# com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause'

Tags: java, mysql

Не могу понять в чем проблема
Есть таблица,
В ней есть usergroupid и username [image: Скрин из myadminа]

Затем есть функция которую я использую в Java

```
public ResultSet queryUserGroupId(String username) throws SQLException

  {
    PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT usergroupid FROM fglad_user WHERE username = ?;", ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    st.setString(1, username);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

    con.commit();

    return rs;
```

В итоге когда я пыатаюсь послать запрос с логионом admin 
Я получаю следующую ошибку в логгере

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause'
```

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: А тот же запрос (копипастом! ну и подставив какой-нить литерал в кавычках вместо знака вопроса) на консоли сервера - выполняется?

Comment: @Akina если прям совсем копипастом то конечно нет,ибо параметр "?" дает ошибку,а если SELECT usergroupid FROM fglad_user WHERE username = "admin" то возвращает все корректно без ошибок

Comment: Ну чудес не бывает... включите General Log на MySQL и посмотрите, в каком виде запрос попадает на сервер... заодно проверьте, не обращаетесь ли не к  той БД.

Comment: @Akina а как включить General Log? я просто с Mysql на "вы" :)

Comment: [The General Query Log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html) *To disable or enable the general query log or change the log file name at runtime, use the global general_log and general_log_file system variables. Set general_log to 0 (or OFF) to disable the log or to 1 (or ON) to enable it. Set general_log_file to specify the name of the log file. If a log file already is open, it is closed and the new file is opened.* Но помните - штука прожорливая. Так что проверяете/задаёте имя файла, включаете лог с консоли, быстренько выполняете запрос из программы, и тут же выключаете.

Comment: @Akina да да загуглил уже,но пишет что нужны привилегии Super... получается надо у хостинга просить включить это?

Comment: а точку с запятой надо? я вроде всегда без неё запросы делал

Comment: Если дело на хостинге - эт фигово, не включат, скажут - тренируйтесь на локальном сервере. Кстати, неплохая идея... Точка с запятой в принципе не нужна, но и хуже от неё не будет. Лучше ставить - дисциплинирует.

Comment: @Akina пойду на локалхосте пробовать...

Comment: @alex убрал точку с запятой ничего ен поменялось,ошибка та же

Comment: @Akina Ты что-то напутал, в каком языке она дисциплинирует.

Comment: Возьмите `username` в обратные кавычки

Comment: @Олексій Моренець все так же:(

Comment: У меня все работает без ошибок